# Product of some binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Is there a special name of the following products of binomial coefficients? If there is, is there a good document listing some properties of these?

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}{n_i-1\choose n_{i+1}}={n_1-1 \choose n_2}{n_2-1\choose n_3}...{n_{k-1}-1 \choose n_{k}}$$

Or, what are possible enumerative interpretations of this formula?

Comment: In what context did you encounter this sum? Is there any reason we should expect it to have interesting properties?

Comment: Maybe it can be expressed as a multinomial coefficient or a formula with a multinomial coefficient? (just an hypothesis).

Comment: @Mike Earnest I encountered these while taking some derivatives of certain formal power series.

Comment: @BillyJoe Yes it can be.

Comment: Probably, I will express it interms of multimonomial coefficients and then use their properties for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
$$
\binom{n_i-1}{n_{i+1}}=\frac{n_i-n_{i+1}}{n_{i}}\binom{n_i}{n_{i+1}},
$$
your product can be written in terms of a multinomial coefficient:
$$
\frac{(n_1-n_2)(n_2-n_3)\cdots(n_{k-1}-n_k)}{n_1n_2\cdots n_{k-1}}\binom{n_1}{n_1-n_2,n_2-n_3,\dots, n_{k-1}-n_k,n_k}
$$